# Error while installing nodejs v18 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, curl, apt

How can i fix this error?

[image]

I got this error when i tried to install nodejs v18 using these commands

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

THE ERROR:

```
E: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Lutris stable' to 'lutris'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

I tried removing the previous node version but it didn't work.

Comment: I think the issue is in your sources.list. I don't known Ubuntu but in Debian you can find all repository paths in /etc/apt/sources.list. You must comment this repo "http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu"

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions; this may fit better on [unix.se] or https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

Execute this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

See the `apt` man page for more info:

```bash
         --allow-releaseinfo-change
           Allow the update command to continue downloading data from
           a repository which changed its information of the release 
           contained in the repository indicating e.g a new major 
           release. APT will fail at the update command for such 
           repositories until the change is confirmed to ensure the
           user is prepared for the change. See also apt-secure(8) 
           for details on the concept and configuration
```

Comment: Even that command gives the same error ```N: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Lutris stable' to 'lutris'
```

Comment: if you fiddle around w `apt update` and then the command I provided?